# Defining a class only works from ipython within

Tags: python, class

I made a class in the folder `mypy`:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def area(self)
        return self.x * self.y
```

if i do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('mypy')
import Shape
test = Shape(2,4)
```

i do get an error:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

If i define the class in `ipython` and call it, everything works fine.

Comment: Either use `test = Shape.Shape(2, 4)` or `from Shape import Shape`. Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: This is a tutorial from wikibook:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IPython the prompt works like a single module, then if you define a class and try to make a object from it like in test = Shape(2,4) will work because you are at the same namespace of the class definition. When you import your module Shape, which have a defined class named Shape too, you have to give the full-qualified name to class definition like in:

```
import Shape
test = Shape.Shape(2,4)   # test = Module.Class()
```